# NoClassDefFoundError when Sending email wiith the library: mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin

Tags: android, mysql, email

I have an issue in my android application when I try to send an email. If I use the library for send mail(`mail.jar`, `activation.jar`, `additionnal.jar`) and connector for android: `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` throws an error:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.timis.util.sendMails.Sendmail$1
at com.example.timis.util.sendMails.Sendmail.sendMail(Sendmail.java:31)
at com.example.timis.tour.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:189)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If I remove `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin` it works well.

Comment: Why do you need a mysql client in your Android app?

Comment: Because, I don't want to have another server for this. It's possible, to use this connector together with library for send mail?  I want to send email from my application, when an user register in my application, and I want to notify him for confirm the email, also use this when an user want to recover the password.

Comment: Well, Android doesn't come with JDBC classes, so you won't be able to use the connector the way you would expect in a server app.  Typically you let the server do all the direct data access and processing.

Comment: But, the connector works very good. This problems is when I sending emails